# How to justify equal sized images in a gallery using margin: auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have image gallery in `div` element "container" with `width:70%`. That images need to be justify with auto margins.

**Here is my html code:** (I have 4 images)

```
<div class="container">         
    <ul class="grid gallery">
        <li class="animation-element">
            <figure>
                <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/638l2frnz/google_logo.png" alt="GINIS">
                <figcaption>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <span>Description</span>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
    </li>           
</div>
```

**And there is CSS code:**

```
.grid {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:left;}
.grid li {
  border:1px solid blue;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;}
```

In this CSS code this (li) is main elements that should be justified.

**Here is my code example:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEybgL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your **css** code:

```
.grid {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.grid > li {
    margin: auto auto 20px auto;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

***Explanation***:

**flex value**: It enables a flex context for all its direct children.

**justify-content**: This defines the alignment along the main axis. It helps distribute extra free space left over when either all the flex items on a line are inflexible, or are flexible but have reached their maximum size. It also exerts some control over the alignment of items when they overflow the line.

**space-around value**: items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them (If the items have the same size).

**margin**: A margin set to `auto` in a flex container absorb extra space.

---

I would recommend you to read about [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix. You can also use flex if you like, as already mentioned, but make sure to add fall-backs if you do. flex may be best in the long run for a gallery.

If not, simply change your `.grid` class as follow:

```
.grid {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
}
```